# How to change the default zoomscale in UIScrollView

Tags: uiscrollview

I have a UIScrollView whose content is UIImageView, I want to show the image 3 times larger when displayed compared to its original size. I set the zoomscale 3. But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set the zoomScale after you set the content of the UIScrollView.